# Pros and Cons of tabular format with one link and hidden divs vs. different links

Tags: seo, search-engines, links

I'm trying to decide the right hierarchy for a website with multiple pages per entity. Each page has the basic general information, and goes deeper according to selected 'tab'. 
Two options I'm considering for this tabular format:

1. Links per tab - meaning each gets his own crawled page
2. All in the same link, toggled with hidden divs (using #).

I feel from a UX perspective, both are fine.

Which will work better in SEO?

Answer (score 2):

SEO has changed a lot these days, experience is everything... You should ignore whats best for the search engines and focus on whats better for your audience. Good experiences go a long way and in turn pages that have rich experiences naturally gain more back links which again in turn improves your SEO more naturally and stronger.

Personally I would only divide the content on numerous pages if the content within the tabs are not related to the main topic, this falls back to user experience as this information would be considered not required if the tab information is not related to what the user has searched for... Google rewards good authority for pages that are about a certain topic and not diluted.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the amount of content per each tab.

If you have enough content or too much content
I suggest Links per tabs, specially if you use Friendly URLs.

This method the pages will load faster and users can bookmark and share each page, so each page will be indexed and can built up page rank.

If you Don't have much content per tab use the Toggle Hide,etc because it will not justify creating a new page from Search engine point of view.